# appending text using loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a help so basically I am making a function where we give URL as input with parameter and then it will modify the value of parameters and then print the modified URL.

```
def findingParams(url):
#url = url+'?name=aman&test=aman'
base_url = url.split('?')[0]
parameters = url.split('?')[1]
myparms = {}
myparms1 = []
payload = "modified_value"

if '&' in parameters:
    #['name=123', 'test=321']
    parameters =  parameters.split('&')
    for params in parameters:
        myparms1.append(params.split('=')[0])
        myparms[(params.split('=')[0])] = payload
        #['name', '123']
        #['test', '321']
    
    print(f'url = {url}\nparams = {myparms}')
    #here I want the ouput as modified parameter

else:
    #print(params.split('='))
    print(base_url)
    print(parameters)
    myparms1.append(parameters.split('=')[0])

    myparms[(parameters.split('=')[0])] = payload
    print(f'url = {url}\nparams = {myparms}')
    #['name', '123']

#myparms = {'name':'123', 'test':'321'}
    for i in myparms1:
        print(f'{base_url}?{i}={myparms[i]}')
        #base_url+?[params]=[payload]
```

I wrote this function and this function works fine with URL that have single parameter eg: `testme.com/test.php?name=123` and I also have to make it work with multiple parameters but the problem is that I don't know How can I use for loop to append value in URL for example: If I'm using for loop then output is like this

```
testme.com/test.php?name=modified_Value
testme.com/test.php?test=modified_Value
```

but I want URL like this

`testme.com/test.php?name=modified_value&test=modified_value`.

Comment: Would using `urllib.parse.parse_qs` help?

Comment: Using a loop to accumulate values is covered in any tutorial on loops.  Splitting a string into desired parts is cover in any string tutorial long enough to include the `split` method.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am stuck at  appending values using loop

Comment: @L3viathan Thanks I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def findingParams(url):
    if "?" not in url:
        print(url)
    else:
        base_url, parameters = url.split("?")
        payload = "modified_value"

        if "&" in parameters:
            modif = ""
            for params in parameters.split("&"):
                name, value = params.split("=")

                modif += name + "=" + payload + "&"
            print(base_url + "?" + modif.strip("&"))
        else:
            print(url.split("=")[0] + "=" + payload)

findingParams("testme.com/test.php")
# testme.com/test.php
findingParams("testme.com/test.php?name=123")
# testme.com/test.php?name=modified_value
findingParams("testme.com/test.php?name=12345&test=12345")
# testme.com/test.php?name=modified_value&test=modified_value
findingParams("testme.com/test.php?name=12345&test=12345&foo=12345")
# testme.com/test.php?name=modified_value&test=modified_value&foo=modified_value
```

Like this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using a temp variable to build the url in your loop, then printing at the end, like this:

```
result = f'{base_url}?'
for i in myparms1:
        result = result + f'{i}=myparms1[i]&'

# remove extra & at end after last parameter
result = result[:-1]

print(result)
```